# Why does symlink() always print symlink failed?

Tags: c, symlink

My code always prints symlink failed even when it creates the symlink, why does this happen?

I am writting all the core utils I use myself as I want the experince and don't like the implementations that exist, I am working on ln and honestly may just do soft links and skip hard links. Right now the program works, but always prints my error and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
        short i;

        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
                if (symlink(argv[1], argv[2]) == -1)
                        printf("symlink failed");

                else
                        symlink(argv[1], argv[2]);
        }
}
```

Comment: You always call it on the same arguments - and if it does succeed, you then call it again...

Comment: Hint: look up `perror()` and `strerror()` for getting human readable error messages when something fails.

Comment: Report error messages on standard error — it exists so that error messages can be kept separate from "normal output". For diagnosing this problem, you should include a diagnostic print operation such as `printf("symlink('%s', '%s')\n", argv[1], argv[2])` where the arguments to the print match the arguments to the system call. You can then see more easily why things are going wrong. You could also report success instead of executing a second (unchecked) symlink which will always fail (either because the first failed and it fails again, or because the first succeeded so the link already exists).

Comment: Also, using `short i` is silly; programs can have more than 32k arguments whereupon your code does not work well.  Granted, most often the argument list is shorter, but they can be massive.  Using `int i` to match `int argc` is sensible.

Answer (score 2):

You're looping over each argument to the program, but attempting to create a symlink from `argv[2]` to `argv[1]` on every iteration. The first one might succeed, but any further attempts will always fail because the link already exists.

You'll want to think carefully about how `ln` should behave when passed more than two arguments. The behavior of `ln -s` is more complex than simply calling `symlink()`; notably, it behaves differently when the last argument is a directory.